# Use Control Key as Key Equivalent- Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm trying to set Control-V as the keyboard equivalent for my Button in interface builder. Unfortunately whenever I type that nothing happens and in the alternatives menu I don't see the ^ character. Obviously I'll have to do this programmatically.

How?

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: That's the answer to a different question. What keyboard layout are you using? Check the Input Sources tab in the Language & Text pane in System Preferences.

Comment: Adding to Peter's question: what version of Xcode are you using? Does Control-anything work? (What you are trying should work, so now the challenge is to figure out why it isn't for you.)

Comment: I think Control is bound to something similar to tab on my system. It always jumps to the next field. Running Xcode 4.6.2

Comment: @centree: That's very weird. What do you see if you press Control with the Keyboard Viewer open? (And, *again*, what keyboard layout are you using?)

Comment: I have this problem, too. Used to be able to do it, can't anymore :-/ Xcode 5.0.2, keyboard layout US, keyboard viewer shows control+command+s light up for me, but I can't set control+command+s as a key equivalent on an NSButton (set it on an NSMenuItem ages ago, though)